# What process is writing /var/log/lastlog

Tags: linux

Google only tell me how to read the content of the /var/log/lastlog, but I really curious to know what process is responsible to write to it?

Answer (score 2):

The [last_log PAM module](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_lastlog)  typically maintains and updates the `/var/log/lastlog` database.

> `pam_lastlog` is a PAM module to display a line of information about the last login of the user. In addition, the module maintains the `/var/log/lastlog` file.
>
> Some applications may perform this function themselves. In such cases, this module is not necessary.

Comment: Okay, thank!  Can user program invoke some API also insert records into this lastlog file?